# buggy behaviour of background-size: cover in DevTools Device Mode

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I wonder if anyone else is having inconsistencies with `background-size: cover` when viewing a page inside Device Mode in Chrome. At times, it displays correctly by stretching the background image to fill the background of the device viewport, at other times the background extends well outside of the viewport (if it's a bigger image), and you have to touch and scroll to view the rest of the image.

Obviously the first method is correct, but it seems to randomly vary whether it chooses to obey the rule or not. Is it just me or my code? I'm using media queries based on min/max-height. Try launching your own examples a few times and let me know if it's always correct or inconsistent.

Just an example with a larger image, which i run with device specs set to 480x800 at 1.5dppx:

```
#container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

@media 
    only screen and (min-height: 800px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.33) and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1.99),
    only screen and (min-height: 800px) and (min-resolution: 128dpi) and (max-resolution: 191dpi) {
    #container {
        background-image: url(v01_1920.jpg);
    }
}
```

Sometimes it will scale the image down to the container/viewport properly. Other times it won't scale down at all. I'm wondering if it's an issues with the UA string, but I'm almost certain all of the devices being emulated will understand one of the two media queries.

Comment: It seems like media queries in general are bugged out inside of Device Mode at this time. I've seen someone recommend trying it out in the lastest Canary build, so I think I'll give that a go.